# Washer pump not engaging for front wipers (possible inverter problem)

Tags: peugeot, water-pump, windshield-washer, pump, bcm

The front washer jets in my Peugeot 206 (year 2000) have stopped working recently - the rear one is still working fine.

The vehicle is using a single twin-outlet pump to control back and front washers. The pump has a two-pin connection (GND, 12V) which, I believe, is inverted by the BCM depending on which washer is needed.

I have checked the most common issues:

- The stalk itself is not the problem - pushing it down normally activates both the wipers and the washers. The wipers still go off when pressed.
- It is not caused by clogged pipes - the motor does not engage for front washers.
- The fuse is also fine.

After connecting a multimeter to the pump's cable, I have discovered that no power is delivered when the stalk is pressed down. When engaging rear washers, -12V can be observed.

How can I diagnose the problem further?

Comment: Possible a Power Relay?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem I had with my 1998 Citroën Xantia, which uses the same sort of washer pump control. I turned out the pump motor was broken, probably a contact problem on the motor commutator. The whole replacement pump costs less than 10 € on the internet (new!). Give it a try.

EDIT: Oh, I just noticed I read wrongly: it's NO power delivered when you press the stalk. Sure?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah pretty sure. Had a multimeter stuck in the connector - showed -12V for rear washers but 0V for front. I think the stalk is fine since the wipers go off but I haven't looked at the wiring diagram yet - may be something odd going on there